# ngx bootstrap modal doesnt fade out even after closing modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

hey tried to use modal in angular2 but when i try to close the modal the modal closes but the fade in doesnt go .
**component**

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" (click)="openDaysModal()">Days Calculator</button>
  public openDaysModal() {

    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DaysCalcComponent, this.config);
  }
```

MOdalComponent 
 for closing it

```
<button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: which component library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use angular animations to trigger such fade-out animations.
for reference: [angular2 animation](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)

Comment: already there but problem is with the fade thing .it doenst go even after (click)="bsModalRef.hide()".